# Strict equality comparison

Tags: javascript, equality

I have contact form. And I use js for form field validation:

```
if(email.length == 0 || email.indexOf('@') == '-1'){
    var error = true;
}
```

but I want to use strict equality comparison for better performance. So I try

```
if(email.length === 0 || email.indexOf('@') === '-1'){
        var error = true;
    }
```

but it isn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Strict Equality, The value should be equal as well as the type should be the same. As per your code the `'-1'` is of type `string` but `indexOf` returns an `number`. The === operator doesn't do the conversion, so even if the values are equal but are not of the same type === will simply return false.

You can try to find the type using `typeof` operator.

So, if you try `typeof '-1'` it would return **"string"**      and
 `typeof 'email.indexOf('@')` would return **"number"**

So, the correct way of doing is to remove the quote around the number -1 as shown below.

```
if(email.length === 0 || email.indexOf('@') === -1){
            var error = true;
        }
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

> Strict equality compares two values for equality. Neither value is
>   implicitly converted to some other value before being compared. If the
>   values have different types, the values are considered unequal.
>   Otherwise, if the values have the same type and are not numbers,
>   they're considered equal if they have the same value. Finally, if both
>   values are numbers, they're considered equal if they're both not NaN
>   and are the same value, or if one is +0 and one is -0.

Answer (score 0):

The [Identity / Strict Equality (`===`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity) Comparison Operator **will not convert types**. This is what separates it from regular equality. [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) will return a number, which is (obviously) not the same as the string `-1`. Theoretically, you could cast one to the other, but the best approach would just be to include the number, like so:

```
if (email.length == 0 || email.indexOf('@') == -1) {
  ... Your Code Here...
}
```